# Ford Figo Starting trouble when engine is hot

Tags: ford, starting, hot-start, figo

I have a 2010 Ford Figo, The car wont restart after a drive.

When the engines cools down it starts without any issue. 
Or else disconnecting and connecting the battery terminal makes it start again
The Battery is just 5 months old AMARON
There is no error code
Checked Pump and Sensors, Checked Rail, Checked Diesel filter. 
I have changed the Injector and Diesel filter lately

Unable to find out what exactly is the issue.

If anyone have any idea, please show some light to identify and rectify the issue.

Comment: It could be an injector issue in most cases. Usually a leak.